# vaadin-server, vaadin-shared bundles are installed in OSGI (karaf 3.0.2)

Tags: osgi, vaadin, vaadin7, osgi-bundle, karaf

I'm struggling with this problem. I have vaadin 7 in OSGI (karaf 3.0.2). 
In list of installed bundles vaadin-server and vaadin-shared status is INSTALLED. although other bundles of Vaadin: vaadin-shared-deps,vaadin-themes,vaadin-client-compiled,vaadin-client are ACTIVE.
Please help me with this issue, I'll really appreciate.

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
Unable to execute command on bundle 203: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.vaadin.shared [203]: Unable to resolve 203.0: missing requirement [203.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.json)(version>=0.0.20131108.vaadin1))

Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
Unable to execute command on bundle 117: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.vaadin.server [117]: Unable to resolve 117.0: missing requirement [117.0] osgi.wiring.bundle; (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=com.vaadin.shared)(bundle-version>=7.3.2)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 203.0: missing requirement [203.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.json)(version>=0.0.20131108.vaadin1))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a bundle that provides the package org.json in a version>=0.0.20131108.vaadin1 .
As the version has vaadin in its name I suspect that the bundle is delivered in the vaadin distro.

Comment: You have to find the bundle that contains this package and install it too in OSGi.

Comment: Pretty cool. I did some tests with vaadin before version 7 but not with the current version. Would be great if you could blog how you did it at some point. Perhaps we can even create a karaf feature for vaadin.